# Python 2.7: Faster/better way to extract all integer values from a string?

Tags: python, string

I want to be able to extract only integer numbers from a user-defined string that includes integers, floats, and strings. I am currently using the split() and isdigit() methods to yank out all the integers and concatenate them to a list:

```
stringy = "If y0u can 66.6 r34d 25 this, you're 29 t00 close."
stringz = [item for item in stringy.split() if item.isdigit()]
print stringz
>> ['25','29']
```

This certainly works, and it's fine for what I need for this particular problem, but it got me thinking; it seems to me that if the string were really long, this might not be the most efficient way to handle the problem. Is there a better way?

Comment: This sort of question is better-suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Is that the case even though the question is theoretical with more of a getting-knowledge bent than a solving-an-actual-problem? I was under the impression that that was more for, well, actual problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a regular expression would work:

```
import re

integers = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)')
integers.findall(stringy)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> stringy = "If y0u can 66.6 r34d 25 this, you're 29 t00 close."
>>> integers = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)')
>>> integers.findall(stringy)
['25', '29']
```

For your shorter input example, the `.split()` and `.isdigit()` list comprehension is still faster though:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('[item for item in stringy.split() if item.isdigit()]', 'from __main__ import stringy')
3.1379640102386475
>>> timeit.timeit('integers.findall(stringy)', 'from __main__ import stringy, integers')
4.119225978851318
```

It improves little with longer inputs:

```
>>> stringy = ''.join([stringy for _ in range(100)])
>>> timeit.timeit('[item for item in stringy.split() if item.isdigit()]', 'from __main__ import stringy', number=10000)
2.5325310230255127
>>> timeit.timeit('integers.findall(stringy)', 'from __main__ import stringy, integers', number=10000)
4.044284105300903
```

Comment: Thank you! Always nice to learn something new.

Comment: @user2113818: I found a slightly faster version, but still won't beat the `.split()` and `.isdigit()` test.

Comment: A slightly shorter alternative for the regex: `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)`

Comment: @F.J: My newer version using `[\b\s]` as anchors is faster; negative and positive lookahead/behinds are unfortunately speed-sinks here.

Comment: I don't think you can put word boundaries in a character class, that will try to match whitespace or a backspace character.

Comment: @F.J: No, it works as expected, actually. `'0'` is matched, `'\b0'` is not.

Comment: Really?  I am seeing an empty list returned on the string `'12 34'`.

Comment: @F.J: Are you using `r''` raw strings? Python 2.7 or Python 3.x?

Comment: @F.J: Bleh, I must have made a session snafu, cannot get it to work now.. Ah, *your* pattern was still referenced. **Duh**.

Comment: @F.J: So, reinstated timings, now with your negative lookarounds.